# A sound/ uncountable sound

Tags: grammar

That is a freshener. It looks like a bell, but it's not a one as it wouldn't create (a/0) sound.

1. A sound.
2. Sound.

What should be the right choice for the sentence above? And if you use sound uncoutably, what context would that be?

Comment: "A one' is not natural; choose between 'a bell'  or 'one'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words **a sound** definitely imply that something will make a distinct sound. A bell, a car, keys jingling.

As far as I understand, the word **sound** is used more generally for something like a speaker spewing music (which can be a different genre of music, volume, or frequency).

Since we are taking about a bell, I would say **a sound** is more native and is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Use the uncountable form when describing general situations where sound occur

> Bats and submarines use sound for navigation